# Performance Tab in Chrome Development Tools shows offset recordings

Tags: performance, google-chrome-devtools, offset, frame-rate

I apologize if a question like this already exists somewhere, but I've really searched carefully and haven't found a question like this one.

[image]

I have a question regarding Performance Tab in the Chrome Development Tools.
I have a difficulty understanding how exactly to interpret it.

In particular, considering a scenario shown in the screenshot, it seems to me like these operations underscored by the blue lines ("recalculate styles", "composite") have been offset to the right, because when I scrub through the FPS chart bar that shows the animation, the timing of the animation starts and ends exactly where the green region does, instead of where the operations themselves start and end.

Is this indeed due to some offset (perhaps a bug in devtools?) or is there some deeper explanation to it that I'm unaware of?

I would appreciate any help as this has been bugging me for quite a while.

EDIT:
I could paraphrase my question in this way as well:
[image]
How did all these frames render if no operations took place like "recalculate styles" and "compositing"?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. However, I'm not quite sure what you really meant.
Did you mean that the screenshot I provided is not enough for you to tell what's the problem, or that the problems lies in the fact that I'm misinterpreting something due to the zoom?

Comment: When I zoom using the mouse wheel the offsets stay absolutely the same, the only thing that changes is the selected range in the FPS chart bar and things zoom in accordingly.

Comment: I misunderstood the question at first. I'm not aware of this bug so I can't help without [MCVE](/help/mcve). Try a different version of Chrome e.g. Chrome Canary or an older portable.

Comment: The question is unclear for me, I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Hey XCS, thanks for the comment.
Let's put it this way - according to Google (https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering), at the part "3. JS / CSS > Style > Composite" it says that the minimal possible rendering activity must include JS, Styles and Compositing. What is confusing to me is that I don't have either styles or compositing happening in each frame even though there is an animation going on in each frame.
I hope this clears it up.

Comment: Pan the chart to reveal the `GPU` strip - maybe it's busy there.

Comment: I think I have realized what the issue is. It seems to stem mainly from my FALSE belief that ALL frames of certain animation have to have Styles and Composite operations happen on them, but in fact, it seems to happen only at the beginning and at the end of the animation. Another crucial misconception that I had is that the mouse movement is not recorded in DevTools, but it is. I still have to test and research this to be certain, and then I will answer my own question for those who will experience the same misconception.

Thank you for your help so far good people of stackoverflow! :)

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED:

I apologize for not returning to this immediately after I solved the mystery for myself. I was very busy in the meantime.

Hereby, I confirm that yes, indeed, the confusion was due to the cursor being recorded (as suspected in the comments) but at the time I wasn't aware of it.
I want to thank everybody in the comments for their suggestions and their will to help.